# Implementing Queue mechanism for concurrent API requests in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, concurrency, grpc, message-queue

I'm doing a WPF Blazor Hyrbid application using Client server architecture. The server side code uses entity framework.

So, there is a use case that I have to handle, where multiple clients (consider 3 for example) will trigger a same gRPC API and in the backend I have to implement a queue such that it is executed one after the other in the backend. These APIs have to update a same record in the SQL Server DB.

I also tried Pessimistic concurrency approach but it needs raw sql query as EF does not support pessimistic concurrency. In my case, I can't use raw SQL. So this option is ruled out.

Is there any variable in GRPC that I can enable so that it will handle the particular API in queue manner?

I checked some online and it seems like I have to implement a message queue or RabbitMQ but since I am new to this, can anyone help me in pointing to the right direction.

Comment: The answer is it depends. You're not showing enough code for a better answer. But I have the feeling a simple [`lock` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/lock) could be sufficient here.

Comment: Exactly what kind of update are you doing? The database should ensure thread safety. But if you are doing more complicated queries you might need a transaction or something else.

Comment: To update the same record in a multiuser environment, with EF you must use **Optimistic Concurrency**. Begin to see how to implement a byte[] RowVersion property, using [Timestamp] annotation, in your table... and after we see the code... (forget to lock the rows, or the table)

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride, my API implementation using the grpc interface will look like this.

public async Task<UpdateResponse> UpgradeDatabase(UpdateRequest request, CallContext context = default)
        {
                var result = await _dataModule.ExecuteCommandAsync(new UpdateCommand(request.Name));
                return new UpdateResponse { Result = result };
            
        }

Comment: @JonasH I have given an example of how my api implementation will look like in the above comment. The data to update will be more like the table will contain 20 columns or so.

Comment: Why are you not adding the code to the question?

Comment: I see nothing that indicates e what kind of queries you are running. But having multiple clients update the same row seem a bit suspect, and there might be better ways to do it. So this smells a bit like a XY-problem. But without a description about what you are actually doing there is no way to tell.